# Android NFC Proof of Concept

Tags: android, android-studio, nfc, nfc-p2p

I have an idea for an android NFC application but am not entirely sure how to implement it.

I want to be able to have an application that is always on (starts on bootup) and the user cannot exit out of the application. I want two have two phones with NFC enabled. One phone is set up as a listener, the other phone is set up as a sender. Both of these devices will have a code. Sender inputs a code (1234), and the listener has a code (123). If the sender puts the phone up to the listener, and the code is incorrect (1234 instead of 123). The device will lock. The only way the device can unlock is if the sender has the same code as the listener.

I don't want code samples.. I just want an explanation of how you would go about doing this.. and if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need your app to start a service after the phone has booted, use BroadCastReceiver which takes action with the BOOT_COMPLETED intent. When that broadcast receiver has been notified of the boot completion you'll start the service which will handle your nfc jobs.